# Airflow question

Tags: hvac

If I setup a 1200 cfm extractor on a basement room, and it will be turned on 24/7 to cool off some computers

will the air of the entire house also be extracted?

and cause the HVAC system to work harder to either cool or warm the house?

Comment: Is the temperature in the computer room reaching unacceptable levels without the extractor fan in place?

Comment: it would, I don't have the computers at hand but based on the research I have made, it can get upwards of 95 degrees

Comment: Yes, it will draw a big vacuum on the house, and any non-direct-vent fuel fired appliances will backdraft and fill the place with hot exhaust gases.  Which will kill you and also make the A/C unable to keep up since it will be fighting both outside makeup air and combustion heat. Did I mention "kill you".

Comment: This also feels like an XY problem.  The "X" is "how do I remove so many watts of heat from this room, to cool computer equipment?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have an extractor, the air has to come from somewhere, and it will come from the rest of the house (and from outside, by whatever openings are available in the house - which can be a particular problem if there are fuel-burning appliances in the house that are not "sealed combustion" - i.e. provided with their own outside air supply. Open flues can backdraft...) So, yes, that will increase your heating and cooling costs, if it doesn't finish you off with carbon monoxide poisoning first.

Using an "extractor" alone to "cool" is foolishness anyway - if you have conditions where the outside air is cool enough to cool your computers, you can bring in that outside air and vent room air (that is, provide both an intake **and** an exhaust vent.) During any part of the year where the outside is too hot for that to work effectively, you simply need more A/C (or to reconsider the economics of whatever you are running all those computers for when you have to pay extra to cool them. Some folks fail to grasp that "mining bitcoin" or running a server farm, etc. is not free when you count the electrical costs.)

During heating season you might want to vent the heat inside the house, as you will have already paid for the electricity to make that heat. In intermediate seasons or cool nights in the summer would be the only time you'd sensibly want to vent the heat outdoors, and for that to be effective you want to bring in cool, fresh air at the same time.

Comment: +1 for "free mining" on bitcoin! (haha). Spot on and to the point about each season, and different applications.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will affect the rest of the house, unless you seal the room off from the rest of the house. Probably the only place you'll need to seal is the door to the room with weatherstripping, unless there are heat ducts in the room.

Remember, for every "outie" there needs to be an "innie". So, when you exhaust air "out" of the room you'll need to provide "make-up air" into the room.

If you don't seal the room from the rest of the house, it will "draw" air from the rest of the house AND the "best" it can be in the computer room is the temperature of the rest of the house.

If you do seal the room, the "best" the temperature can be is the current outside temperature. (And don't forget to add a relief duct with damper to the exterior.)

You may need an air conditioner.